# Deleting every XElement occurrences with specific name in an XDocument returns an error

Tags: xml, vb.net, runtime-error

I'm implementing a system with a 'recently opened files' system. basically when the user opens a file via the program a XML node is added to data.xml which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<!-- Core Data -->
<!-- Should NOT be messed with as this may corrupt your files! -->

<Data>
    <RecentlyOpenedFile>Libraries\Documents\company.blue</RecentlyOpenedFile>
    <RecentlyOpenedFile>C:\File.blue</RecentlyOpenedFile>

    <CurrentVersion>1.0.0</CurrentVersion>
</Data>
```

Now I need to implement a button that basically removes all instances of a node called 'RecentlyOpenedFile' (as in clear recents list). So I have this code:

```
Sub ClearRecent()
    Dim DataDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(dataFile)
    For Each curElement As XElement In DataDoc...<RecentlyOpenedFile>
        curElement.Remove()
        DataDoc.Save(dataFile)
    Next
End Sub
```

But when I run ClearRecent() it returns the following error: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of the items then iterate that list in reverse order.

```
Dim xmlTree As XElement =
     <Root>
       <Child1>child1 content</Child1>
       <Child1>child2 content</Child1>
       <Child1>child3 content</Child1>
       <Child1>child4 content</Child1>
       <Child5>child5 content</Child5>
     </Root>

Dim child = xmlTree.<Child1>
For i As Integer = child.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
  child(i).Remove()
Next
Debug.WriteLine(xmlTree.ToString)
```

Output:

```
<Root>
 <Child5>child5 content</Child5>
</Root>
```